# plot marker in googlemap from json data android

Tags: json, google-maps, android-asynctask

i want to get my locations from my database in format json via webservice and plot markers in googlemap. i have delopped this code. when i debug it i can see the data parsed but i have error in add marker. 
before posting here i have already looked at all the similar question.
this is my code i want to know where is the problem.

```
public class MyLocation extends Fragment{
public MyLocation(){}private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;private String urlnearby="http://myserver/api/relations/relations_nearby/latitude/48.8633216/longitude/2.337843399999997";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylocation, container, false);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }


        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();


        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean enabledGPS = service
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean enabledWiFi = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!enabledGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    new NearbyAsyncTask().execute(urlnearby);
    return view;
}

class NearbyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.cancel();

        if (result == false){
            //show a msg to user that data not parsed
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status ==200){
                //get the response and pars it
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("nearby");
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++ ){
                   JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   String title = jRealObject.getString("title");
                  String img =  jRealObject.getString("image");
                  String lat=  jRealObject.getString("latitude");
                   String lng= jRealObject.getString("longitude");

                  double  latitude=Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    double longitude= Double.parseDouble(lng);
                   MarkerOptions near = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(title);
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(near);

                }

                return true; //verifie the parse
            }

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //http call
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconstruct your code to work correctly.

You need to put your async task returning an object with the data you need in onPostExecute function.

Then, in the activity, you create a function to load the markers returned from async task.

You can see a good example of using async tasks [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: you have results? some other question?

Comment: sorry i just tried it this morning,it work fine thank you , but i make the async task return a list because i want to have more informations.

Comment: i want to set the image in the info window have you any idea how to make it?, the images are from my database not from google maps

Comment: If this question is resolved please approve them and make another question. Send me here the link of the new question here. I will be happy to assist you in the new question.

Comment: tks... send-me the link of the new question. i try to help you

Comment: this is the link for the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431446/plot-a-different-marker-for-each-place-googlemap-v2-android