# plot a different marker for each place googlemap v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, marker

I have managed to place a marker for each item in my database using their stored title and coordinates.

I am now trying to change the content of each InfoWindow so that it shows information related to each place (other than the title and snippet)also each place have a different icon marker. how to give a custom icon and a different infowindow for each place?
i create the different icons for marker. 
the information are loading in format json and the icon marker are also in my database.should i load them or put them in drawable folder.

Comment: If the images are lower resolution then put in drawable folder.

Comment: actually i'm avoiting the method to put them in drawable folder because in the future there can be another marker if the database will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Google covers most of what you want to do in their Google Maps API v2 documentation.

[Info Window Customization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows) and [Customizing a MArker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker) have code example how-to's. For your marker icons, are they just a different colour marker or are they completely customized? Storing them in drawable is ok and can be accessed easily using

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_custom_marker))
```

when creating/adding the Marker.

Comment: the marker are completely customized, (hotel marker, theatre marker...). the problem i'm getting my data via web service and i have stored the marker there, i want a method to load them via url because there in the future the database can be updated so there will be another marker.